# Why am I seeing US job adverts when I am based in London?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I no longer seem to be seeing London jobs (in the sidebar on "Questions").

https://www.whatismyip.com/ correctly tells me that I am in London.

Has something gone awry with the geo targeting?

I refreshed the page a few times and these are the ads I saw - none are specifically UK based.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I thought I had a similar issues yesterday on seeing a job in Bangalore. In my case closer reading of the job showed it to be a London (my location) company recruiting for a job in Bangalore.

Comment: IIRC, there are airports in London, one quite large, with many international flights.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit are you suggesting that I commute to Kansas?

Comment: @MartinSmith are there direct flights?  Monday and Friday redeyes are an annoyance, but it depends on how much you get paid?

Comment: @MartinSmith free snack fridges

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not seeing this issue - I'm also in London, and seeing UK ads.

I just looked up some of your recent IP addresses using https://www.iplocation.net/ - at least one of them shows up as a US IP address in one of the databases (although it is correctly showing up as a UK IP address on others).

So it looks to me like this is just one of those things that sometimes happens with geo-location - it can never be 100% accurate unfortunately.

Comment: Is there anywhere in jobs for users to manually specify where we’re interested in working?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are no jobs in the UK that match your user profile settings, so SE is publishing jobs of other locations.

Another posibilty is that you have your OS location setting spoofed, disabled, or your using the onion ring addon in your browser?