# Why am I seeing jobs tagged with the wrong location?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I am located in the Paris region, and I have recently started seeing this job ad:

[image]

That's very nice, and I might even be interested in working at ARM in Paris, but when I actually click the link to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/arm I see 16 jobs, 9 of which are in Cambridge UK, the rest in the USA, and 0 in Paris.

Why does the job ad claim (or suggest) that ARM has jobs in Paris when that is not the case?

Note that this is not a duplicate of all the posts where Stack Overflow gets the poster's location wrong. It does get my location right. It gets the location of the *jobs* wrong.

**This is *not* a duplicate** of [Why am I seeing US job adverts when I am based in London?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349449/why-am-i-seeing-us-job-adverts-when-i-am-based-in-london). In that question, a person in London had IP addresses that placed them in the USA, which is why they were shown jobs *correctly labeled* as located in the USA. I am a person in Paris with IP addresses in Paris, and I am being shown jobs that are *incorrectly labeled* as located in Paris.

Comment: I've seen this happen as well, although not as bad. Job was advertised in Sydney, but the job was actually in Melbourne.

Comment: I think it might be just indication of a branch/office location in Paris. Sort of like "Hey, ARM is a company with an office in your location which has open jobs". Also I don't know what sort of options does an job advertiser have on displaying their adverts on SO. Maybe they have a selection of location where to display job advertisements regardles of the actual location of the position?

Comment: Some of the jobs offer relocation so perhaps that's enough for you to see the ad? I guess it's a slight lie/miscalculation in the UI to then say it's based in Paris.

Comment: 5-10k is a reasonable range that says how big is the company? There is no difference if its 6 ppl or 9999? Whats next range 10k - 500k? lol

Comment: @TJ that's got to be 5k-10k

Comment: @CalvT Ah that makes sense. Maybe I'm just dumb :) Or maybe not...

Comment: @CalvT indeed, it's 5k-10k people as seen on their company page https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/arm (which says "5001-10000 employees").

Comment: @Tas: The distance between Sydney and Melbourne is almost twice the distance between Paris and Cambridge ;-)

Comment: @thepio: I don't think it's a Paris branch. By coincidence, I did take a hard look at jobs at ARM a while back, and I saw jobs all over the world but nothing in France. I'm fairly sure they have no development offices here.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie ok, then it must just be an option for the advertiser to display it in your country/city/area. As mentioned in comments above it might be due to relocation offers etc.

Comment: ARM do have offices in Paris, along with offices in Grenoble and Sophia Antipolis - https://www.arm.com/company/offices/offices-europe - but they might not be an office that gets many specific job adverts.